# WSL session can not survive hibernation in No Hyper-V Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, hibernation

In order to run VirtualBox I have to disable Hyper-V features by editing bcd as follows:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 10"
bcdedit /set {current} description "No Hyper-V"
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype Off
```

But when I run Windows in "No Hyper-V" my WSL session can not survive a hibernation, as the system wakes up WSL session disappeared.
Any advice? Thanks,